# How to connect mongoDB Compass to mongoDB container which runs in azure VM?

Tags: mongodb, azure, docker, mongodb-compass

I have mongoDB container which runs on azure VM, and I'm trying to connect it to my mongoDB compass.
I have Public IP address to my VM, the port 27017 is open in my vm and also in my mongo container.

I have authentication, so to connect my mongo I'm Enter the mongo container and write the command "mongo -u username -p password --authenticationDatabase admin" (Relevant).

When I'm trying to connect I get "connection timed out" error message.

```
docker container ls
```

[image]

**Open ports on the VM**

[image]

**My compass login page**

[image]

Comment: Get docker connectivity working locally before trying on azure.

Comment: it's already done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by changing the configuration file of the mongoDB container.

**Step 1**:, make sure port 27017 is open on the VM:

[image]

**Step 2**:, create a mongoDB configuration file as below, name it mongod.conf, and change the bindIp field to your host IP (change < Host IP> to your host IP).

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /data/db
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,<Host IP>


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

security:
  authorization: enabled

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

**Step 3**: Copy the mogod.conf file into your VM, and save it wherever you want.

**Step 4**: Run the command:

```
 docker run -d -v <FolderPathOnTheVM>/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf -p 27017:27017 mongo -f /etc/mongod.conf
```

Make sure you changed the < FolderPathOnTheVM> to the path of the mongod.conf file on the VM (The path of step 3).

Answer (score 0):

Do netstat on 27017 and check if its running on localhost or public IP. If its running on localhost, then change it to your public IP in mongodb config file and then retry. Also, telnet from your local machine to the mongodb IP and port to check if its working locally.